# Ignore comments with whitespace in regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I modify the following line of code (which reads the names of parameters in `config_file`):

```
re.findall('Parameter.*', config_file)
```

so as to ignore lines containing a comment symbol (`%`) to the left? i.e. in the following example,

```
Parameter: A
%Parameter: B
  %  Parameter: C
 Parameter: D %the best parameter
```

only A and D match?

Comment: Is there anything but `%` and spaces, that could come between the line start and `Parameter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I would argue that there are two parts to the question; asking about the negative lookbehind and asking about ignoring whitespace. The linked question doesn't fully answer this one.

Comment: @SebastianProske only `%` and spaces :)

Comment: @colopop agreed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\n))\s*Parameter.*`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ss7JFZ/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\n))` - finds the position which is just preceded by a `\n` or start-of-the-string
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of white-spaces
- `Parameter.*` - matches `Parameter` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character(except newline characters)

Comment: I was just about to leave a comment about the lack of explanation -- thank you for preempting me. Also, good catch that this pattern could match after a newline as well as the start of the string.

Comment: This will fail to match when input is `foo Patameter: M` but requirement is to ignore only `%` lines

Comment: @anubhava Although that requirement was not mentioned by the OP, but I guess we can use [`(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\n))[ ]*(?!\s*?%).*?Parameter.*`](https://regex101.com/r/Ss7JFZ/2) for that case.

Comment: Why so complicated, you can just use: `(?m)^[^%]*Parameter.*`

Comment: @anubhava That certainly looks better.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of regex alternation and capturing groups in `findall`:

```
>>> test_str = ("Parameter: A\n"
...     "%Parameter: B\n"
...     "  %  Parameter: C\n"
...     " Parameter: D %the best parameter")
>>>
>>> print filter(None, re.findall(r'%\s*Parameter|(Parameter.*)', test_str))
['Parameter: A', 'Parameter: D %the best parameter']
```

Matches that you want to discard should appear before the last capturing group match in an alternation.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3e7m6A/1)